# How to trigger an event after clearing the DIV

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am using `backbone and Marionette` for my Application.I want to create my own event like If `div` innerHTML clears the event should be trigger.

html code :

```
<div id="firstDiv"></div>
```

While div clearing time, I want to unbind the view events.In my Application,we have Main button to go main page.This button common in every screen,So I written a code for this button,once use click on this button div clears and main page will be render,the problem was still the previous view events are listening.So How can I clear the previous View events.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: call the function when div is empty on particular event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that, to the best of my knowledge. You can listen to events triggered by *the browser* (click, focus, etc.), and you can also listen or trigger events on Backbone/Marionette instances.

What you'd like to do is trigger an event on a specific DOM change, which you can't do. Instead, when you clear that div, you should trigger an event yourself and have your code listen for that event.

Comment: While `div` clearing time, I want to `unbind` the view events.In my Application,we have `Main` button to go main page.This button common in every screen,So I written a code for this button,once use click on this button `div` clears and main page will be render,the problem was still the previous `view` events are listening.So How can I clear the previous View events.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to say that you should be thinking about how you can capture this within the view logic, rather than listening to a DOM change.

That said, if you do think that listening to the DOM is the best approach, then this could be a good use case for a Mutation Observer. Explaining how is a little above and beyond, but there is a lot of good information on the [MDN Dev page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Marionette, you should not worry about the previous view events. It automatically handles the Garbage Collections and unbinds the previous events. You have to make the application in such a style that when you render a View in a Region, it will bind the events to that, and when you click on button "Main" you should handle route to get the new View/stored View to be shown in that same region. So the old view will be removed automatically and the events will be also removed. Marionette is best at that part.

And if you have custom events using jQuery I suggest

```
  Use Marionette View's events
OR
  Use  $(element).off("event").on("event", function(){});
```